# Paranormal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is said to be paranormal if for any $g\in G$, we have  $\langle H, H^g \rangle = H^{\langle H, H^g \rangle}$

A characterisation of such a subgroup is:

A subgroup $H \leq G$ is paranormal $\iff$ for any subgroup $K$ such that $H\leq K$, all conjugates of $H$ lying in $K$ also lie in $H^K$, the normal closure of $H$ in $K$.

So I assume $H$ is paranormal and let $g\in G$ such that $H^g \leq K$. Then $\langle H, H^g \rangle \leq K$ and since $H$ is paranormal, we have $H^{\langle H, H^g \rangle} \leq K$. I'm not sure how to continue

Comment: I'm sorry to do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/th4WZ.jpg), but I've never heard of a paranormal subgroup before; I don't know why that terminology is so amusing to me.

Comment: So $H^g \le H^K$ which what you are trying to prove. The $\Leftarrow$ direction is also straightforward. I think you should  try a bit harder to solve this yourself.

Comment: @pjs36 I confess that I was unable to suppress a childish smirk when I first heard of subnormal subgroups long ago as a student. But you soon get used to it.

Comment: Is it true that if $H \leq A \leq B$ then $H^A \leq H^B$?

Comment: That follows immediately from the definition $H^A = \langle h^a : a \in A, h \in H \rangle$.

Comment: $H^a \leq H^B$ for all $a\in A$ since $A \leq B$. Thus $H^A \leq H^B$

Comment: Okay the $\Rightarrow$ direction is done. What subgroup should I consider for $K$ in $\Leftarrow$ direction?

Comment: Okay let the assumption hold. Now $H \leq \langle H, H^g \rangle$ and $H^g \leq \langle H, H^g \rangle$ then by the assumption, $H^g \leq H^{\langle H, H^g \rangle}$ thus $\langle H, H^g \rangle \leq H^{\langle H, H^g \rangle}$ . By definition $H^{\langle H, H^g \rangle} \leq \langle H, H^g \rangle$. Hence $H$ is paranormal in $G$. Is that fine?